# Which "Thing" stickers are effective against Bowser?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

I've reached Bowser in his castle, and I've lost the battle quite a few times. It seems that, for all of the space they take up in my album, the "thing" stickers I've got aren't very effective against Bowser.  Which "thing" stickers are most effective (do the most damage) against Bowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single Thing sticker which does massive damage to Bowser, but these Things carry their own weight:

- Any kind of scissors (1 square = Sewing Scissors)
- Any cold damage (1 square = Shaved Ice)
- Boombox

The scissors and cold Things each have a specific use during the battle, and the Boombox is useful because it doubles Mario's attack.